# Sonar violation: Invoke method(s) only conditionally

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

Our company just started a sonar farm. I was curious about our code quality and wanted to improve.

I have a code containing such logger calls:

```
LOGGER.error(String.format("Cannot load object in status %s (%s)", status, statusDescription), e);

LOGGER.info(String.format("%s object(s) loaded in status %s (%s)", objects.size(), status, statusDescription));
```

Sonar triggers rule squid:S262, Invoke method(s) only conditionally *"Preconditions" and logging arguments should not require evaluation*. Rule triggered by both theses lines.

About this one, I'm not really sure to understand what's going on. The explanation seams not well fitting to my use case. Sonar doc provided this example:

```
logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Something went wrong: " + message);  // Noncompliant; string concatenation performed even when log level too high to show DEBUG messages
```

which I perfectly understand (debug will not be logged in production, thus unnecessary operations will occurs). But for info and error level, I would assume that you want to log it anyway. Moreover, in my case, I want both to be logged.

Which is the good approach ? 
Rewrite differently not using String.format ? Tune sonar to not fire on info/error level ? Just ignore sonar on this one ? Something else ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your concatenation will be done before the condition check in the logger. So if you call the logger 10 times and the evaluation returns false, your strings will be concatenated 10 times too with no reason. The logger will handle all concatenation and formatting after it's evaluation is passed and it needs to print something, that way you're saving up on useless operations.

```
LOGGER.error("Cannot load object in status {} ({})", status, statusDescription, e);
```

Comment: How to solve this for logger methods which do not take an arbitrary amount of strings, but only one additional one? In this example there is `status` and `statusDescription` and so four parameters are passed to `error()`. What if `error()` doesn't take as many arguments?

Comment: If your logger implementation doesn't support format string + vararg string arguments you can do an if(logger.isErrorEnabled()){...} and do the string concatenation (formatting) and logging inside the if body. That way you will achieve the same result - avoid the cost of string concatenation if the logger is not in the correct logging level.